# how to git add a relative path

Tags: bash, git

How do I git add a file in a different directory using relative path?

Say I have 2 files in 2 different directories:
somerepo/a/fileina and somerepo/b/fileinb.
For example, if I'm currently in directory "a" (user:~/somerepo/a) and I want to use git add to stage changes in "fileinb" using a relative path. what the command line looks like?

Should I type:"git add ./b/fileb" or "git add ./../b/fileb". I'm confused about what . in git means.
Thanks

Comment: `.` means current directory, `..` is one directory back.

Comment: Do you think "git add ../b/fileb"  IS the correct answer for the question? thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You can also add all files from the root of the git repo using `git add -A :/`. Just in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In virtually all places in Git where you specify a path, `.` means the same thing as anywhere else: the current/same directory. So, `./b` is equivalent to just `b`, and `x/./y` is equivalent to `x/y`.

In your case, you'd want to go one directory up, meaning your second suggestion is correct, but you don't need the leading `./`, you can just say `git add ../b/fileb`.